# update_attributes failing when I try to update an attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a user database as User(id: integer, username: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, password_digest: string, admin: boolean, usermanager: boolean).
I want to update an user and make him Admin, setting the admin varaible to true.

My update in the controller:

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "User edited"
  redirect_to current_user
else
  render users_url
end
end
```

The update_attributes is failing in all cases. I opened a debugger and tried to call update_attributes, it is failing there as well.

```
(byebug) user_params = {"admin"=>true}
{"admin"=>true}
(byebug) @user
#<User id: 1, username: "dsmegha", created_at: "2015-09-11 07:42:01", updated_at: "2015-09-13 03:25:01", password_digest: "$2a$10$BInH6J1dXHanqNIdGag6megSyrmm95AmjTEGPemNdGU...", admin: false, usermanager: nil>
(byebug) @user.update_attributes(user_params)
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'dsmegha' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
false
```

The update_attribute works for the same.

```
(byebug) @user.update_attribute(:admin,true)
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
true
(byebug) @user
#<User id: 1, username: "dsmegha", created_at: "2015-09-11 07:42:01", updated_at: "2015-09-13 03:25:01", password_digest: "$2a$10$BInH6J1dXHanqNIdGag6megSyrmm95AmjTEGPemNdGU...", admin: true, usermanager: nil>
(byebug)
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: what parameters are permitted in your `user_params`?

Comment: private
   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :admin)
    end.

Comment: is there any Validation?

Comment: has_many :timezones, dependent: :destroy
 VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/
 validates :username, presence: true, length: { minimum:6, maximum: 15 },
    format: { with: VALID_USERNAME_REGEX },
    uniqueness: true
 validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 15 }
 has_secure_password

 
Not for the :admin field

Comment: If you are only updating `admin` field, then try `@user.update_column(:admin, true)`. Check is it works or not.

Comment: Yes, the update_column works. Thanks. But any idea why the updates_attributes is not working? I will need to parse the user_params to :admin,true and then use the update_column. I need to have a similar update_column for removing admin privilages and making an user UserManager as well. (byebug) @user.update_column(:admin, true)
  SQL (156.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "admin" = 't' WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 4]]
true

Comment: It is probably a validation error. Check user.errors.messages, you will get more idea

Comment: The error says password can't be blank. But I am not touching this attribute at all. (byebug) @user.errors.messages
{:password=>["can't be blank", "is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}
(byebug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I think current user data is invalid. please check `user.errors`.

example)

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

pry

```
 pry(main)> user = User.last
=> #<User:0x007fe328fe56d8
 id: 3,
 email: "hogehoge@example.com",
 name: "",
 encrypted_password: "$2a$10$I.xXo0AtAz8nuCUzOGclPe6PA//XMZtjW6fh94D1t25jb7eV9bsS.",
 current_sign_in_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:53:08 JST +09:00,
 last_sign_in_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:52:20 JST +09:00,
 current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
 last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
 created_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:49:40 JST +09:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 13:16:26 JST +09:00,
 confirmation_token: nil,
 confirmed_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:52:01 JST +09:00,
 confirmation_sent_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:49:40 JST +09:00,
 unconfirmed_email: nil,
 failed_attempts: 0,
 unlock_token: nil,
 locked_at: nil,
 status: 1>

[7] pry(main)> user.update_attributes(status: 2)
   (0.1ms)
        BEGIN
   (0.2ms)
        ROLLBACK
=> false

[8] pry(main)> user.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe328d893f8
 @base=
  #<User:0x007fe328fe56d8
   id: 3,
   email: "hogehoge@example.com",
   name: "",
   encrypted_password: "$2a$10$I.xXo0AtAz8nuCUzOGclPe6PA//XMZtjW6fh94D1t25jb7eV9bsS.",
   reset_password_token: "XWmjsEBujb2-aWd5YHYT",
   reset_password_sent_at: nil,
   remember_created_at: nil,
   sign_in_count: 2,
   current_sign_in_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:53:08 JST +09:00,
   last_sign_in_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:52:20 JST +09:00,
   current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
   last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
   created_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:49:40 JST +09:00,
   updated_at: Sun, 13 Sep 2015 13:16:26 JST +09:00,
   confirmation_token: nil,
   confirmed_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:52:01 JST +09:00,
   confirmation_sent_at: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 01:49:40 JST +09:00,
   unconfirmed_email: nil,
   failed_attempts: 0,
   unlock_token: nil,
   locked_at: nil,
   status: 2>,
 @messages={:name=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

---

additionally write.

View has password input field perhaps? In that case, I think you need to delete passward params when update user data.

How about this?

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable

  validates :name, presence: true

  def update_without_current_password(params, *options)
    params.delete(:current_password)

    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    end

    clean_up_passwords
    update_attributes(params, *options)
  end
end
```

controller

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_without_current_password(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "User edited"
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render users_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. However I am using bcrypt and my password will be empty and the password_digest will be created. Using update_column is the way around this? #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f57633c0c28 @base=#<User id: 4, username: "UserManager", created_at: "2015-09-12 16:07:51", updated_at: "2015-09-13 04:22:03", password_digest: "$2a$10$Kv8OsQrsq/L1xClxVevWq.HafT8EApIQEwXuePuHeQe...", admin: true, usermanager: true>, @messages={:password=>["can't be blank", "is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}>

Comment: Maybe I think you need to delete passward params when update user data . I written add answer.